# How to ignore \n while using matchadd to highlight long lines in vim

Tags: regex, vim, neovim

I have these two lines in my vimrc

```
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=magenta guibg=magentam
call matchadd('ColorColumn', '\%81v', 100)
```

But when I have lines that has exactly 80 characters, vim still shows that line at column 81 due to the '\n' at virtually col 81.

[image: Screenshot with my config]

**Is there a way to ignore the newline character when doing matchadd to display a warning line?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `\%v` matches with zero width, you can limit the match to any character that is not a newline at column 81 with this command:

```
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=magenta guibg=magentam
call matchadd('ColorColumn', '\%81v[^\n]', 100)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm! (I guess I really need to learn some regex.)